# Access to SD card on Sony DSC-QX100 camera via Remote Camera API?

Tags: api, camera, sony

I'm working with a Sony DSC-QX100 camera via Sony's Remote Camera api, specifically for use on a Windows 8 tablet (basically replacing the built-in camera of the tablet with this unit). I'm able to consume the camera's LiveView (streaming) and LiveShot (take a picture and retrieve the image from url) features triggered from my application.

My question is whether or not the Remote Camera api exposes any functionality to access pictures stored on the camera's SD card (when it is available). Bottom line, my user may choose to take the picture directly with the camera unit (manually, instead of remotely via my application on the tablet) and I've not yet found the method by which to retrieve this picture from the camera (other than transferring the SD card from camera to pc). Anyone tried this or seen something in the API documentation that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Current Camera Remote API does not provide direct access to SD card.
All available APIs are documented.